# Where to get parameters for ClientId and impersonatedUserId(UUID) in the RequestJWTUserToken method in Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi

I am requesting an access token to DocuSign using RequestJWTUserToken, signature is as below

```
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Request JWT User Token Configures the current instance of ApiClient with a fresh
            //     OAuth JWT access token from DocuSign
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   clientId:
            //     DocuSign OAuth Client Id(AKA Integrator Key)
            //
            //   userId:
            //     DocuSign user Id to be impersonated(This is a UUID)
            //
            //   oauthBasePath:
            //     DocuSign OAuth base path DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.Demo_OAuth_BasePath
            //     DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.Production_OAuth_BasePath DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.Stage_OAuth_BasePath
            //     DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient.GetOAuthBasePath DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient.SetOAuthBasePath(System.String)
            //
            //   privateKeyStream:
            //     The Stream of the RSA private key
            //
            //   expiresInHours:
            //     Number of hours remaining before the JWT assertion is considered as invalid
            //
            //   scopes:
            //     Optional. The list of requested scopes may include (but not limited to) DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE
            //     DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.Scope_EXTENDED
            //
            // Returns:
            //     The JWT user token
            public OAuth.OAuthToken RequestJWTUserToken(string clientId, string userId, string oauthBasePath, Stream privateKeyStream, int expiresInHours, List<string> scopes = null);
```

Where to get parameters for **ClientId** and **impersonatedUserId**(UUID) in the RequestJWTUserToken method in Docusign?

[PrintScreen for DocuSign -> Settings -> Apps and Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSl2l.png)

Comment: You have to configure some of this stuff on the docusign account by creating a developer account and then adding your application to it. This is a walkthrough on this from their documentation - (https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/), please also see - (https://developers.docusign.com/platform/configuring-app#integration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

impersonatedUserId = API Username in the Apps and Keys page.

clientId = integration Key for your specific key in the Apps and Keys page.